# How to get null for rows where data doesn't exist in Postgres while performing joins

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-design

[image: Image for reference]

I have 2 tables: Items and Rates. Items and Rates are linked using a FK on Rates. If the rate of the item is not present for the day then it is not stored. So for item 5 if no rate is present on 1st January there won't be a record for item 5.

I want item 5 rate as null.

How can I proceed?

Left Join is not working; depending on the data, sometimes I get the date as null, sometimes everything except the item PK is null.

Comment: Can you please share your models?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A left join is the right approach, but you need a table that contains all the rows that you want in the result, and you don't have that.
But you can create it with a distinct cross join of your tables.

```sql
select to_char(x.date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), x.pk, rates.rate 
from (
    select distinct date, pk
    from items, rates
) x
left outer join rates
on x.pk = rates.item
and x.date = rates.date
order by x.date, x.pk
```

produces

| to_char | pk | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-2023 | 1 | 10 |
| 01-JAN-2023 | 2 | 12 |
| 01-JAN-2023 | 3 |  |
| 01-JAN-2023 | 4 |  |
| 01-JAN-2023 | 5 |  |
| 02-JAN-2023 | 1 | 11 |
| 02-JAN-2023 | 2 |  |
| 02-JAN-2023 | 3 | 13 |
| 02-JAN-2023 | 4 | 14 |
| 02-JAN-2023 | 5 |  |

With the following setup:

```sql
create table items(
  pk integer,
  name varchar(50)
);
    
create table rates(
  item integer,
  date date,
  rate integer
);
    
insert into items (pk, name) values
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C'),
    (4, 'D'),
    (5, 'E');
        
    
insert into rates (item, date, rate) values
    (1, '1-Jan-2023', 10),
    (1, '2-Jan-2023', 11),
    (2, '1-Jan-2023', 12),
    (3, '2-Jan-2023', 13),
    (4, '2-Jan-2023', 14);
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMtnPeC5aPr6SJLN7HWd5g/0)

Comment: Thank you, will try. Cant do distinct as there are over a billion rows in the rates table, but will pass dates as an array and use them to join

Comment: If you cannot do distinct then you are prepared to accept duplicates. If not then, depending on your tolerance for stale data, create a materialized view joining `items` and `rates` with distinct. Then use it in place of the sub-select.  Your are trading disk space for query time and not having duplicates. Question then becomes *is it worth the cost?*